# C2143 C2059 errors with terniary operator

Tags: visual-c++, c-preprocessor, ternary-operator

```
bool xHasReached(double tX, double dstX, bool incX) {
return incX ? tX > (dstX - (double)EPSILON) : tX < (dstX + (double)EPSILON);}
```

So I am getting C2143 (missing token) and C2059 (syntax error) errors. I've tried without the semicolon but is still reports the same errors.

I've tracked the bug down to EPSILON #define.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A couple of things that would help us answer the question: Show the full message of C2143 and C2059, so that we won't have to look it up elsewhere. Also please show the EPSILON #define. To add these things to the question, use the edit link under the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bet you have `#define EPSILON 0.0001 ;`.

That should have been `const double EPSILON = 0.00001;`. Macro's are harder to debug, they tend to cause errors when used rather then when defined.